# MySQL - Update multiple values and WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Is there any syntax like WHERE IN allow me to update multiple values at once?
example:

```
update files
set name = 'untitled' 
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

become:

```
update files
set name ( 'untitled', 'untitled2', 'untitled3', 'untitled4' )
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

My script contains an associative array, I need to update the name column set as array value where the id column match the array key

Comment: just use serialize() function to convert array to string and then write it to name column, and when you read data user unserialize() to convert string to array

Comment: You misunderstand my question, I don't want to run SQL multiple times

Comment: @AleksandarVasić this violates the principle or RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a `case` statement?

```
update files
    set name = (case when id = 1 then 'untitled'
                     when id = 2 then 'untitled2'
                     when id = 3 then 'untitled3'
                     when id = 4 then 'untitled4'
                end)
    where id IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

In MySQL, you can also do this with a `join`:

```
update files f join
       (select 1 as id, 'untitled' as newname union all
        select 2, 'untitled2' union all
        select 3, 'untitled3' union all
        select 4, 'untitled4'
       ) n
       on f.id = n.id
    f.name = new.newname;
```

If you have a lot of values, you can create a table with the values separately and then do the update.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question isn't oversimplifying the real issue you have, you could use the [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
UPDATE files
SET    name = CONCAT('untitled', id)
WHERE  id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: how about something like `'abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl'`